# how to display all folder and sub folder from FTP using c# windows application?

Tags: c#, ftp

i want to display the all the files and sub folders from FTP using c#

how do i do?
can you one upload code?

i have tried import data from FTP in Tree view.but i cannot do

my code:

```
private TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(string root, string p)
        {
          var directoryNode = new TreeNode("CGT");


            var directoryListing = GetDirectoryListing(path);

            var directories = directoryListing.Where(d => d.IsDirectory);
            var files = directoryListing.Where(d => !d.IsDirectory);

            foreach (var dir in directories)
            {
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(dir.FullPath, dir.Name));
            }
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
            }
            return directoryNode;
        }
```

Leave this code this for example only..you people please help me out of here

Comment: Could you please explain, why you think your code is not working and what you have tried so far?

Comment: i am not did anything,i tried with some example code only..that is not working